# pyqtgraph: How to add radiobuttons on a figure legend?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I want to control which curves are displayed at the figure by using the radiobuttons floating on the left-top corner, which will work also as a legend. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by inheiring `pg.LegendItem` and overriding `addItem` method. In it you need to create widgets and place them into layout. You can use `QGraphicsProxyWidget` to display `QRadioButton` on `QGraphicsScene` (PlotWidget).

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.graphicsItems.LegendItem import ItemSample
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class LegendItem(pg.LegendItem):

    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._group = QtWidgets.QButtonGroup()

    def addItem(self, item, name):
        widget = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(name)
        palette = widget.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.WindowText, QtCore.Qt.white)
        widget.setPalette(palette)
        self._group.addButton(widget)
        row = self.layout.rowCount()
        widget.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clicked.emit(row))
        proxy = item.scene().addWidget(widget)
        if isinstance(item, ItemSample):
            sample = item
        else:
            sample = ItemSample(item)
        self.layout.addItem(proxy, row, 0)
        self.layout.addItem(sample, row, 1)
        self.items.append((proxy, sample))
        self.updateSize()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    plt = pg.PlotWidget()
    plt.setWindowTitle('Legend with radiobuttons')
    
    legend = LegendItem(verSpacing=5, horSpacing=5)
    legend.setParentItem(plt.getViewBox())

    plt.plotItem.legend = legend

    c1 = plt.plot([1,3,2,4], pen='r', symbol='o', symbolPen='r', symbolBrush=0.5, name='red plot') 
    c2 = plt.plot([2,1,4,3], pen='g', fillLevel=0, fillBrush=(255,255,255,30), name='green plot')

    def onClicked(index):
        print("{} clicked".format(index))

    legend.clicked.connect(onClicked)

    plt.show()

    app.exec()
```